# В какой таблице БД хранятся информация о заказе в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, база-данных

Для синхронизации из внешним приложением используем подключение к базе данных сайта. Мы не может найти где хранятся способы доставки у заказа. Скорее всего это таблица "wp_postmeta". Но у просмотренных заказов, мы не нашли ни одного "meta_key" с похожими данными.

Как называется таблица со способами доставки ?

Comment: Никогда не лезь базу! Для этого к ВП есть АПИ.

Answer (score 0):

Способы доставки хранятся в таблице `woocommerce_order_itemmeta`, кажется поле `meta_key=method_id`.

Comment: Не нужно фантазий - в вопросе о WC ни слова. и даже метки такой нет.